# Can I get a Facebook Fan Page to appear in my fan's newsfeeds?

Tags: facebook

I have a [Fan Page](http://www.facebook.com/draw3cards), where I keep pushing latest information from [my site](http://draw3cards.com/). I seem to recall that in the past, these updates were visible on my newsfeed. Right now though, I don't see any of these updates in my feed.

Is there a way to get these "status updates" to appear in my feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still get status updates in my feed. Facebook "intelligently" decides what should appear in a user's feed, so if the user regularly interacts ("likes" posts, comments, etc) with a Page, it will show it in their news feed. You probably don't get updates in your news feed any more because you as a user (other than as a Page administrator) don't interact with the page. You will have done when you first started because you had only just added the page.

Comment: Heh, I checked and my Facebook page stopped importing status updates from my twitter app about a month ago. I'll go fix that, I think the rest will take care of itself. Thanks.